# base64.encodestring failing in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, base64, python-3.4

The following piece of code runs successfully on a python 2 machine:

```
base64_str = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username,password)).replace('\n', '')
```

I am trying to port it over to Python 3 but when I do so I encounter the following error:

```
>>> a = base64.encodestring('{0}:{1}'.format(username,password)).replace('\n','')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 519, in _input_type_check
    m = memoryview(s)
TypeError: memoryview: str object does not have the buffer interface

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 548, in encodestring
    return encodebytes(s)
  File "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 536, in encodebytes
    _input_type_check(s)
  File "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 522, in _input_type_check
    raise TypeError(msg) from err
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str
```

I tried searching examples for encodestring usage but not able to find a good document. Am I missing something obvious? I am running this on RHEL 2.6.18-371.11.1.el5

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can `encode()` the string (to convert it to byte string) , before passing it into `base64.encodestring` . Example -

```
base64_str = base64.encodestring(('%s:%s' % (username,password)).encode()).decode().strip()
```

Comment: Hi Anand, Thanks for your response. When I tried what you suggested, I got the following error:
`>>> base64_str = base64.encodestring(('%s:%s' % (username,password)).encode()).replace('\n', '')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object
`
Please advise.

Comment: I added an `decode()` call in between (added in the answer) , `encodestring` returns a byte string, we cannot directly call `replace()` on it.

Comment: I changed replace('\n', '') to strip() to make it more readable.

Comment: how to replace `\n` if they are in the middle of the  string,the `strip()` doesn't work

Answer (score 11):

To expand on Anand's answer (which is quite correct), Python 2 made little distinction between "Here's a string which I want to treat like text" and "Here's a string which I want to treat like a sequence of 8-bit byte values". Python 3 firmly distinguishes the two, and doesn't let you mix them up: the former is the `str` type, and the latter is the `bytes` type.

When you Base64 encode a string, you're not actually treating the string as text, you're treating it as a series of 8-bit byte values. That's why you're getting an error from `base64.encodestring()` in Python 3: because that is an operation that deals with the string's characters as *8-bit bytes*, and so you should pass it a paramter of type `bytes` rather than a parameter of type `str`.

Therefore, to convert your `str` object into a `bytes` object, you have to call its `encode()` method to turn it into a set of 8-bit byte values, in whatever Unicode encoding you have chosen to use. (Which should be UTF-8 unless you have a ***very specific*** reason to choose something else, but that's another topic).

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3 encodestring docs says:

> def encodestring(s):
>       """Legacy alias of encodebytes()."""
>       import warnings
>       warnings.warn("encodestring() is a deprecated alias, use encodebytes()", DeprecationWarning, 2)
>       return encodebytes(s)

Here is working code for Python 3.5.1, it also shows how to url encode:

```
def _encodeBase64(consumer_key, consumer_secret):
    """
     :type consumer_key: str
     :type consumer_secret: str
     :rtype str
    """
    # 1. URL encode the consumer key and the consumer secret according to RFC 1738.
    dummy_param_name = 'bla'
    key_url_encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode({dummy_param_name: consumer_key})[len(dummy_param_name) + 1:]
    secret_url_encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode({dummy_param_name: consumer_secret})[len(dummy_param_name) + 1:]

    # 2. Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character “:”, and the encoded consumer secret into a single string.
    credentials = '{}:{}'.format(key_url_encoded, secret_url_encoded)

    # 3. Base64 encode the string from the previous step.
    bytes_base64_encoded_credentials = base64.encodebytes(credentials.encode('utf-8'))

    return bytes_base64_encoded_credentials.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
```

(I am sure it could be more concise, I am new to Python...)

Also see: http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/

Answer (score 1):

This worked with me as a replacement

`base64.encodebytes(('%s:%s' % (username, password)).encode('utf8')).decode('utf8').replace('\n', '')`